# Fixing the dataset for zipcode to county conversion in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dataset

I have this dataset that has been working pretty well for me to convert zip code to the county, but the problem is that it doesn't list all of the zip codes in a traditional way (although most of them are listed in a normal 5-digit format). For example: 10090 or 10080 that can't be found because it is listed as "100HH" in the dataset. 29071 can't be found either since it is listed as "290XX" (also, I think they might have gotten the county wrong for this one since I think it is supposed to be Lexington county, not Richland, but I'm not sure). I want it so that if someone inputs in "10090" it will be interpreted as "100HH" to find the right county. This seems simple, but I found over 1100 different "XX" and "HH" zipcodes in this dataset. Any suggestions are helpful! Thanks!

```
library(httr) 
urlCounties <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scpike/us-state-county-zip/master/geo-data.csv"
zipcodeToCountyData <- content(GET(urlCounties), type = 'text/csv')

zipcodeToCounty<- function(zip) {
    tbl.county <- subset(zipcodeToCountyData, zipcode == zip) 
      countyName <- tbl.county$county
      stateName <- tbl.county$state
      return(list(countyName, stateName))
}
```

Comment: Is there a common key such that `H` could mean any number? Or that `HH` has special meaning for a specific set of zones only? How does `X` differ in that regard? (And why are the states wrong? I don't know anywhere that thinks `New york` and `New mexico` are correct. Seems like some code was a little too eager on *"Sentence case conversion"* versus *"Title Case Conversion"*.)

Comment: Hindsight: the census.gov [defines](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/guidance/geo-areas/zctas.html) ZCTAs `HH` for large bodies of water without zip codes, and `ZZ` as large bodies of lands without zip codes; and in the 2010 census, allegedly this practice was retired. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following.  But I'm not really sure how you want to decide whether you want the XX or the HH.

```
library(tidyverse)
zipcodeToCounty<- function(zip) {
  tbl.county <- subset(zipcodeToCountyData, zipcode == zip) 
  if(nrow(tbl.county)==0){
    tbl.county <- zipcodeToCountyData %>% 
      filter(str_sub(zipcode, 1,3) == str_sub(zip,1,3)) %>% 
      arrange(zipcode) %>% ## HH as first choice ??
      head(1)
  }
  countyName <- tbl.county$county
  stateName <- tbl.county$state
  return(list(countyName, stateName))
}
```